# How do I change the value of an input in jsp without Javascript?

Tags: html, jsp, dom

Say I have an input named run:

```
<input name="run" value="false" type="hidden"/>
```

How do I change it's value to

```
<input name="run" value="true" type="hidden"/>
```

before submitting the form?

Comment: If you don't wanna use javascript. You can open the code in an editor and replace it yourself, then rerun your app, then hit submit. Or you can change it on the server using Java

Comment: Yeah Ive definitely been changing it from the editor lol. It seems like it doesn't get replaced when its assigned a second time.

Comment: What do you mean by `It seems like it doesn't get replaced when its assigned a second time.`?

Comment: What happens is when I declare value="true", its still read as "false" when the form is submitted...

Comment: So you manually change to `value="true"` in your editor, but it still sends `false` to the server? If that is the case, it is just impossible